# The getter 'buffer' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Uint8List>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement image uploading feature and this is the snippet of code I am using which worked properly in previous versions of Flutter but is giving this particular problem in the current version.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
var image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
var base= image!.readAsBytes();
List<int> imageData = base.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Comment: Could you clarify which error you are seeing when running this code?

Comment: I'm not sure if ti will solve the problem but can you try this: `var base = await image!.readAsBytes();` and tell me if the error changes or if it fixes it?

Comment: `File.readAsBytes` returns a `Future<Uint8List>`.  Either `await` it or use `readAsBytesSync()` to get the `Uint8List`.  Also see: [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63017280/)

Comment: @jamesdlin It worked do post this comment as an answer so that I can upvote and select the answer.

Comment: @StefanGaller It says The getter 'buffer' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Uint8List>'
for 3rd line of the code snippet